# Proof involving Poisson and Gamma distributions for two random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

Prove that if $X_i \sim \text{Poi}(λ_i)$, $i = 1, 2$, are independent, the sum $X_1 + X_2$ has the Poisson distribution as well.

Prove that if $X_i \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha_i,\beta)$, $i = 1, 2$, are independent, the sum $X_1 + X_2$ has the gamma distribution as well
($i$'s are meant to be subscript).

I am not sure how to go about solving these problems, help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: These questions have already been asked and answered before on this website. Try searching them.

Answer (score 0):

The respective characteristic functions are $\exp[\lambda(\exp it-1)]$, $(1-it/\beta)^{-\alpha}$.